# Dynamic Flask Checkbox Form Composition with WTFlask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am having some trouble applying the code in the [WTForms documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specific_problems/) to my use case (see "Dynamic Form Composition" section). My goal is to use a list of strings (`list_a`, of variable length) as an argument to produce a series of checkbox forms. For example, if `list_a = ['one, 'two']`, then the output would be a form with two checkboxes labeled "one" and "two". The documentation says to use this:

```
def my_view():
    class F(MyBaseForm):
        pass

    F.username = StringField('username')
    for name in iterate_some_model_dynamically():
        setattr(F, name, StringField(name.title()))

    form = F(request.POST, ...)
    # do view stuff
```

and in my attempt to appropriate it, I've come up with this:

```
def wrapper_func(list_a):
    class Prefs(FlaskForm):
        pass

    for ele in list_a:
        setattr(Prefs, ele, BooleanField(ele) )

    form = Prefs(request.POST, ...)
```

Can anyone help me clean this up to get it to work? I'm not sure what else goes in the last line, or if a list is even allowed in this context. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question it's hard to decide whether you are using [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/) or [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/). The documentation link points to the former, while your example uses the `FlaskForm` class, which is part of the latter.

The following minimalistic example is made using WTForms.

Project structure:

```
your_project_folder
├───forms
│   ├───__init__.py
│   └───dynamic_form.py
├───templates
│   └───main.html
├───venv
│   └───your_virtual_environment_files
└───server.py
```

`dynamic_form.py` contains your wrapper function without the form instantiation (it just returns the dynamically created form class):

```py
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField


def wrapper_func(list_a):
    class Prefs(Form):
        pass

    for ele in list_a:
        setattr(Prefs, ele, BooleanField(ele))

    return Prefs
```

`main.html` contains the HTML code with Jinja2 syntax to generate the form:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div>{{ field.label }}: {{ field }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`server.py` puts everything together:

```py
from flask.app import Flask
from flask import request, render_template, redirect
from forms.dynamic_form import wrapper_func


app = Flask('form_app')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    input_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']  # generate it as needed
    prefs = wrapper_func(input_list)
    form = prefs(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        # do your logic with the submitted form data here
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template("main.html", form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=3456, debug=True)
```

The last two lines are strictly for development purpose!

Please let me know if this example helps!